# UE5 Problems - Build Error: OtherCompilationError

Tags: c#, c++, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to build to **package my UE5 game project**. But the output log always shows an exception below:

```
. . .

CompilationResultException: Error: OtherCompilationError  

   at UnrealBuildTool.ActionGraph.ExecuteActions(BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, List`1 ActionsToExecute, List`1 TargetDescriptors) in d:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\System\ActionGraph.cs:line 375

   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Build(TargetMakefile[] Makefiles, List`1 TargetDescriptors, BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, BuildOptions Options, FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile) in d:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 611

   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Build(List`1 TargetDescriptors, BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, BuildOptions Options, FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile, Boolean bSkipPreBuildTargets) in d:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 282

   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Execute(CommandLineArguments Arguments) in d:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 237

   at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main(String[] ArgumentsArray) in d:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.cs:line 612

 . . .
```

There's something worth to be noted:

- I migrated this project from **UE4.26** to **UE5.0**
- There're also some warnings and errors above the exception which are:

  1. `...\ShooterGame\Private\UI\Menu\Widgets\SShooterMenuWidget.cpp(33): error C2065: 'Visibility': undeclared identifier`
  2. `...\ShooterGame\Private\UI\Widgets\SShooterDemoHUD.cpp(80): error C2065: 'ColorAndOpacity': undeclared identifier`
  3. `...\Engine\Plugins\...\Camera\CameraShake.h(7): warning: UCameraShake has been renamed to UMatineeCameraShake, change to #include "MatineeCameraShake.h" and rename references`

I'm so confused right now cuz I can't tell if it's a c++ **C2065** problem or an **UnrealBuildTool** one.

Comment: You have C++ compilation errors. You'll need to fix those.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah I saw those errors. But I have no idea that I should make forward declaration or what. In the original ShooterGame project, the header files are well included so I don't understand why undeclared identifier errors pop up.

Comment: Well, I can't see the code so I can't really help with that. I'd start by replacing the deprecated class with the current one. If the other two errors aren't caused by that then you'll need to figure out where those things came from before and figure out where they come from now. You'll have to do some research.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It finally solved after I replaced these identifiers with getter and setter functions. So grateful for your support!